# How can Arduino Mega2560+Wifi Shield 2.0 (seeedstudio) receive data from database in xampp server on my pc

Tags: php, http, arduino, xampp, wifi

I'm trying to connect my Arduino Mega via wi-fi to my xampp server.
My main objective is get a value at my database and store it on a variable in Arduino code. With this new variable I'll be able to control the rest of the program... so for that matter I need your help. Can someone give-me advice?

I already try every thing that i found in the internet but it just dosen't work.

I think that the simple way is to send a GET request to the server and read his response... but for some reason i cant send the GET request trought...

I test it on the browser directly and the value show up, so i think that the server side is allright.

Here is my Arduino Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "WiFly.h"  
#include "HTTPClient.h"

#define SSID      "mySSID"
#define KEY       "myKEY"

#define AUTH      WIFLY_AUTH_WPA2_PSK

#define HTTP_GET_URL "http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/send_data_db.php/?$temp=0"

// Pins' connection
// Arduino       WiFly
//  2    <---->    TX
//  3    <---->    RX
SoftwareSerial uart(10, 11);
WiFly wifly(uart);
HTTPClient http;
char get;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);    
  Serial.println("------- WIFLY HTTP --------");


  uart.begin(9600);         // WiFly UART Baud Rate: 9600
  // Wait WiFly to init
//  delay(3000);

  // check if WiFly is associated with AP(SSID)
  if (!wifly.isAssociated(SSID)) {
    while (!wifly.join(SSID, KEY, AUTH)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to join " SSID);
      Serial.println("Wait 0.1 second and try again...");
      delay(100);
    }

    wifly.save();    // save configuration, 
  }


Serial.println("\r\nTry to get url - " HTTP_GET_URL);
  Serial.println("------------------------------");
  while (http.get(HTTP_GET_URL, 10000) < 0) {
  }
  while (wifly.receive((uint8_t *)&get, 1, 1000) == 1) {
    Serial.print(get);
  }

  if (wifly.commandMode()) {
    Serial.println("\r\n\r\nEnter command mode. Send \"exit\"(with \\r) to exit command mode");
  }
}


void loop() {
  int c;
  while (wifly.available()) {
    c = wifly.read();
    if (c > 0) {
      Serial.write((char)c);
    }
  }

  while (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c >= 0) {
      wifly.write((char)c);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("./connection/database_connect.php");
include("./top_table.php");

if((isset($_SESSION["ID"])) AND (isset($_GET["temp"])))
   {
        $id=$_SESSION["ID"];

        $sql="SELECT temp FROM perfil, client WHERE perfil.ID ='$id'";


        $consult=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $result=mysqli_num_rows($consult);

        if(($result==1))
        {
            $person_data=mysqli_fetch_array($consult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $temp=$person_data["temp"];

            header("HTTP/1.1" . " " . 200 . "OK");
            header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            header("Content-Length: 1112");
            header("Connection: close");
            header("/r/n");
            echo $temp;

        }
        else
        {
            //se user dosen't exist on data base
            header("Location: http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/login.php");
            exit;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: http://192.168.1.80/xampp/training/login.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```